# Programs and Features has a different color scheme, how to reset

Tags: windows-10, color-theme

Hello after  running disk cleanup for previously installed windows, programs and features has a different color scheme. How can I reset it to what it should look like?[image]

Comment: Check your theme settings in *Settings > Personalization > Themes*. Check also *Colors* for the Dark theme.

Comment: I tried resetting it to light then back to dark. No luck.